# How to automatically generate an OpenAPI documentation from a jsonresult response?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, swagger, openapi, swashbuckle

Swashbuckle can automatically generates API documentation based on code (with details return model)

```cs
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult<List<Student>> GetStudents()
{
    return CollegeRepository.Students;
}
```

[image: API document]

Is there any way to make Swashbuckle automatically generates API documentation a JsonResult?

```cs
[HttpGet]
public JsonResult GetStudents()
{
    var json = new JsonResult(new
    {
        data = CollegeRepository.Students,
        message = "success"
    });

    json.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status200OK;

    return json;
}
```

Comment: Do you mean save documentation Provided on Json Format?

Comment: @AnujKarki Yes, I mean components/schemas, example value

Answer (score 1):

You could do something similar as below.

```cs
public static void SaveSwaggerJson(this IServiceProvider provider)
{
    ISwaggerProvider sw = provider.GetRequiredService<ISwaggerProvider>();
    OpenApiDocument doc = sw.GetSwagger("v1", null, "/");
    string swaggerFile = doc.SerializeAsJson(Microsoft.OpenApi.OpenApiSpecVersion.OpenApi3_0);
    var root = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory ?? "~";
    string swaggerDir = Path.Combine(root, "swagger");
    if(!Directory.Exists(swaggerDir))
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(swaggerDir);
    }
    string fileName = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM_dd_yyyy_hh_mm_ss_") + "swaggerfile.json";
    string filePath = Path.Combine(swaggerDir, fileName);
    File.WriteAllText(filePath, swaggerFile);
}
```

In this above, I have saved file on the basis of time. You could modify it as per you need.

It use `SerializeAsJson` function from `ISwaggerProvider` which returns Json data as you wanted.

Comment: Hi, it seems I almost understand what you mean. Where do I put this code, how does it work?

Comment: Parameter in this function uses `this` keyword which means you could call function from instance of `IServiceProvider` itself.

For eg, 
`var app = builder.Build();
app.Services.SaveSwaggerJson();`

Comment: it oke to save then I can edit manually. So may can not automatically generate document